# Wireshark vs Netmon for precise time tagging

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to time tag and get some statistics on multicast traffic. When there is not much traffic, the stats looks good, but as soon as there is a bunch of packets arriving at the same time, I have stats that are not even possible (e.g. round trip time of 0ms)

I'm wondering if Netmon could be more precise in time tagging packet because it is not relying on the Winpcap driver?

Does anybody already faced the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try MS [Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226). It uses quite precise time measurement with seven decimal places.

[image]